# Comparacion de listas con retorno de booleano

Tags: c#

Tengo dos listas `IEnumerables` las cuales debo comparar para hacer que los ids de las listas se me proyecten en una grilla, los `ids` son profesionales de equipos y la comparación es para cuando se seleccionen a dos profesionales, la lista devuelva los equipos donde solo ellos estén EJ:

```
public async Task<MiniEquipoModel> GetMiniEquipoGrillaAsync(SearchFilter filter,
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
//Buscar profesionales que coincidan en miniequipos
  var MiniEquipo = await _miniEquipoCommonRepository.GetMiniEquipoByProfesionalAsync(filter, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

var result = new MiniEquipoModel();

var grupoMiniEquipo = new List<MiniEquipoCommonModel>();

foreach (var item in MiniEquipo.ListaMiniEquipo)
{
 if (ValidarProfesionalesMinimos(item.Ids, filter.PersonaIds))
 grupoMiniEquipo.Add(item);
}

result.ListaMiniEquipo = grupoMiniEquipo;
result.Total = MiniEquipo.Total;

return result;
}


  #region Métodos privados

        private bool ValidarProfesionalesMinimos(IEnumerable<int> ids, IEnumerable<int> personaIds)
{
 var profesionalIds = _miniEquipoRepository.GetProfesional(ids);
 var result = profesionalIds.SequenceEqual(personaIds);

 return result;
}
        #endregion
```

en el metodo privado como lo hago para que me retorne la comparacion en "true" (hasta el momento me retorna false y eso hace que en la parte de arriba en el IF no se me añada el item en GrupoMiniEquipo), nesecito que me retorne true en la comparacion en el metodo privado. pero no se como  hacerlo bien

Comment: ¿y la pregunta es?

Comment: en el metodo privado como lo hago para que me retorne la comparacion en "true" (hasta el momento me retorna false y eso hace que en la parte de arriba  en el IF no se me añada el item en GrupoMiniEquipo)

Comment: Sugiero entonces editar tu post e incluir claramente cual es tu problema, el comportamiento esperado y qué es lo que funciona mal, con la redacción actual no queda claro, y los comentarios no son el lugar donde debe quedar especificada la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

[SequenceEqual](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2) compara que los elementos sean iguales y **en el mismo orden**. La lista [1, 2, 3] no es igual a [3, 2, 1] para este método.  Lo que puedes hacer es ordenar ambas listas antes:

```
lista1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(lista2.OrderBy(x => x));
```